# Submit form to add column in table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a table like this:

```
<table id="criteria-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" class="text-center align-middle">#</th>
      <th rowspan="2" class="text-center align-middle">Employee</th>
      <th colspan="3" class="text-center">Order</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center">Priority</th>
      <th class="text-center">Criteria</th>
      <th class="text-center">Unit</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr class="tr_template">
      <td class="text-center">1</td>
      <td class="text-center">Employee A</td>
      <td class="text-center">75%</td>
      <td class="text-center">10</td>
      <td class="text-center">order</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And I have 2 button in the end of this table:

```
<a class="btn btn-add-criteria  btn-sm m-btn--icon color" href="javascript:void(0)">
  <i class="la la-plus"></i>ADD CRITERIA
</a>

<a class="btn btn-add-employee  btn-sm m-btn--icon color" href="javascript:void(0)">
  <i class="la la-plus"></i>ADD EMPLOYEE
</a>
```

When I click add criteria button, a popup will open to type criteria data and submit:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="popup-add" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content clear-form">
      <!-- Body modal -->
      <div class="modal-body">

        <!-- Form -->
        <form id="frm-add-criteria">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <div class="m-form__group">
                <div class="criteria-content">

                  <!-- Criteria -->
                  <div class="row modal-row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                      <label class="font-weight-bold">Criteria</label>
                      <div class="input-group">
                        <select name="kpi_criteria_id" id="kpi_criteria_id" class="form-control">
                          <option value="1">Order</option>
                          <option value="2">Contract</option>
                          <option value="3">Revenue</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <!-- Priority -->
                  <div class="row modal-row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                      <label class="font-weight-bold">Priority</label>
                      <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="priority" name="priority" placeholder="Input criteria" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <!-- Amount -->
                  <div class="row modal-row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                      <label class="font-weight-bold">Amount</label>
                      <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="kpi_value" name="kpi_value" placeholder="Input amount" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Footer modal -->
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <div class="m-portlet__foot m-portlet__no-border m-portlet__foot--fit ss--width--100">
              <div class="m-form__actions m--align-right">
                <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-metal bold-huy m-btn m-btn--icon m-btn--wide m-btn--md">
                  <span class="ss--text-btn-mobi">
                    <i class="la la-arrow-left"></i>
                    <span>CANCEL</span>
                  </span>
                </button>

                <button type="submit" onclick="" id="btn-save-criteria" class="btn btn-success color_button son-mb  m-btn m-btn--icon m-btn--wide m-btn--md btn_add_close m--margin-left-10">
                  <span class="ss--text-btn-mobi">
                    <i class="la la-check"></i>
                    <span>SAVE</span>
                  </span>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </form>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

After I submit the form in modal, it will add one more column like this for all employee row in table:

[image]

Here is my old table:

[image]

After submit form modal:

[image]

Same like this, when I click add employee, it will show a modal for me to choose employee, then it will insert one more employee row to this table with all criteria I add before.

Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/az3n4x2p/) to show you what I did.

I really don't know how to do this so forgive me if you feel I just give you about code not solution.

Hope you can give me a good advise to handle this.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use JS / JQuery DOM manipulation.
here's an example using JQuery and Bootstrap:

Table

```
<table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tableBody">
                <tr>
                    <td>John</td>
                    <td>Male</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
            Add Person
        </button>
```

I put an id to the table body (tbody) element so I can access it directly from script side using JQuery.

Modal

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Insert Person</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label>Name</label>
                        <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label>Gender</label>
                        <select id="gender" class="form-control">
                            <option>Choose Gender</option>
                            <option>Male</option>
                            <option>Female</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addPerson()" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I put id on every input for JQuery access. and since we are not to sending it to a database or another http request, there's no need for a form.

The JQuery Script:

```
<script>
    function addPerson() {
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var gender = $('#gender').val();
        var html = '';

        html += '<tr>';
        html += '<td>' + name + '</td>';
        html += '<td>' + gender + '</td>';
        html += '</td>';

        $('#tableBody').append(html);

        $('#name').val('');
        $('#gender').val('Choose Gender');
    }
</script>
```

first I make 3 variables to contain empty string, the value of name, and the value of gender. then I make a table row mock up and fill it with the values from name and gender on that empty string variable, after that I add the new data to the table using the $('#tableBody').append(html); command. and then refresh the form using $('#name').val('');and $('#gender').val('Choose Gender');. hit me up if you need more elaboration.